# Character Transfer Overlap?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I have been playing GTA V Xbox one since Christmas and I originally bought GTA V on Xbox one with a shark card included. I used that 1.25 million to become a CEO with a warehouse. Now I am missing my cars and other things from the 360. So I was wondering if I transferred my character would there be any way for me to keep my CEO office but get the cars and apartments I had before?

Answer (score 1):

No. The transferred character and it's properties and cars would be in a different character slot. The money would be shared between all characters though. So you could try to sell the cars, and change the properties by a cheap house to get some more money back.